# Can we invoke method outside the thread block by any technique in C#? so that we can use same thread method to invoke other methods as well.?

Tags: c#, multithreading

e.g.
Here in this example, if I want to start thread on method M1 this way,
Purpose is I need to call M2, M3 on same thread method to avoid repeated code.
Is this possible in C#?

```
static void Main()
{
    if(StartThread() => M1()) //I want to invoke Method M1 from here like this    
    {
        return;
    }
}        

private void StartThread()
{
    var t = new Thread(() => M1()); //I dont want to invoke Method M1 from here
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
    t.Join();
}
    
private static void M1()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: What is the actual goal? "I need to call M2, M3 on same thread method to avoid repeated code" makes no sense, you are not repeating code when calling it.  You should typically use tasks rather than raw treads, and you can use a [limitedconcurrencyTaskScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-6.0) to prevent running methods concurrently.

Comment: It's impossible to tell what you actually need here, you've not shown us any realistic code. All you've shown us is you using a mechanism (Threads) that you're likely using incorrectly (it's rare that you would Start a thread and immediately Join to it). It's usually better to use something like Tasks where you focus on *the work to be done*, **not** the mechanism.

Comment: Not just rare: Calling `t.Join()` immediately after calling `t.Start()` is practically _always_ a bad idea. It means that the caller is not doing anything _concurrently_ with the new thread. But doing something concurrently with the new thread is the only reason for ever creating a thread in the first place. Creating a new thread only makes sense if you're going to call `t.Start()`, _and then do something else while the thread is running,_ and then finally, call `t.Join()` when there's nothing left to do.

Comment: I'd look into the `ThreadStart` delegate. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadstart?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Just use a delegate (e.g. an `Action`) and pass it to `StartThread`:

```
static void Main()
{
    if(StartThread(() => M1()))
        return;
}        

private void StartThread(Action a)
{
    var t = new Thread(() => a());         
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
    t.Join();
}

private static void M1()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```